# Do i need to use RobustScaler() and OneHotEncoder() in new data before model.predict()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-scaling

Suppose I have this dataframe (in a regression problem) with `numerical` and `categorical` data:

```
                                            df_example

Var1_numerical   Var2_categorical   Var3_numerical   Var4_categorical    Var_to_predict
    20                red            1                    BK                  352352
    10                blue           4                    BL                  345341
     5                orange         6                    BA                  423423
     1                red            3                    BK                  342342
    90                orange         2                    BK                  456456
```

So, in one part of the process I will use `RobustScaler()` on the numeric variables and `OneHotEncoder()` on the categorical variables so that the model can learn from these variables. And now I will have my model trained to predict with a certain error for that prediction.

The interesting thing is to predict on new data using `model.predict()`

```
pred_list_example=[15, red, 1, BK]
a = np.array(pred_list)
a = np.expand_dims(a, 0)

model.predict(a)
```

**Question 1:** Do I need to use `RobustScaler()` and `OneHotEncoder()` on `pred_list_example` before using `model.predict(a)`?

**Question 2:** In case the answer to the previous question is "yes", the `Var_to_predict` will be scaled due to `RobustScaler()`. Do I need to use `RobustScaler().inverse_transform` to get the original numeric value of the prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question 1:** Do I need to use `RobustScaler()` and `OneHotEncoder()` on `pred_list_example` before using `model.predict(a)`?

Yes, and more than that: you must use the *same* `RobustScaler()` or `OneHotEncoder()` to do the transformation, or it won't know how much to scale by or what order your one hot categories go in.

> **Question 2:** In case the answer to the previous question is "yes", the `Var_to_predict` will be scaled due to `RobustScaler()`. Do I need to use `RobustScaler().inverse_transform` to get the original numeric value of the prediction?

Yes, though note a subtlety: `RobustScaler()` requires a certain number of columns, and scales each one by a different amount. This means that there's no easy way to give it just your Y variable, and ask it to undo the transform on this one variable.

For this reason, I suggest having two `RobustScaler()` instances: one for your X variables and one for your Y variable, so that you can undo scaling on a predicted Y variable without having the X variables to go with it.

There is also the question of whether it is even needed to scale Y variables. Some people would say that it's not necessary. You can read a pro and con argument [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111467/is-it-necessary-to-scale-the-target-value-in-addition-to-scaling-features-for-re).